# Purpose of travel in visa application

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I am scheduling an appointment with the embassy because I'm going to Greece for an Erasmus internship (Youth Exchange). What should I write for the purpose of visit: tourism or business?

Comment: Will you be there for more than 90 days?

Comment: No 10 days only..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the VFS site, which you report requires you to choose "tourism" or "business," I would suggest that you choose "business" because an internship is closer in nature to a business visit than it is to a tourist visit.

When you get to the application form, however, you will be using the standard Schengen visa application form because you will be applying for a short-stay visa.  There are many more options for "purpose of travel" aside from just "tourism" and "business":

- Tourism
- Business
- Visiting family or friends
- Cultural
- Sports
- Official visit
- Medical reasons
- Study
- Transit
- Airport transit
- Other (please specify)

You could reasonably choose *cultural,* but if I were completing the application form I would probably choose *other* and write "Erasmus internship."

Comment: OK thanks alot but im scheduling an appointment throwing their website and theres only  "tourism" and "business" ..

Comment: @MajdiAlturk Can you post a link to the website?  I would like to have a look.  Thanks.

Comment: ok but you have to make a new account and then choose ( scheduling an appointment ) heres the link http://www.vfsglobal.com/greece/jordan/know_your_visa_type.html

Comment: @MajdiAlturk aha. This reminds me of yesterday's question [What is correct when applying for a visa: VFS or Embassy guidelines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/122619/19400)  It seems that third-party contractors don't always understand everything very thoroughly. You are right that I do not want to go as far as creating an account.  But I have edited the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: @MajdiAlturk It occurs to me that if you choose business, VFS might want to see business sponsorship evidence (an employer letter, for example).  If you can ask VFS which option to choose, you should do that.  Their contact information is on the page you linked to, under *HELPLINE.*